# SAPUI5. Odata. Сохранение нескольких записей

Tags: sap

Нужно сохранить несколько одинаковых записей (с разными ключами) из приложения SAPUI5.
Несколько вызовов oModel.create("/Set", oData) намекают, что может сохранить только одну запись.
Ок, в цикле добавляю параметр и вызов уже выглядит так:

```
var mParameters = {};
mParameters.groupId = "changesGroup" + i; //i - переменная цикла
oModel.create("/Set", oData, mParameters);
```

затем, опять же, но в другом цикле вызываю:

```
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["changesGroup" + i]);
oModel.submitChanges();
```

но при этом вызывается сохранение только последней записи, причём столько раз, сколько было шагов цикла.

Как обмануть систему, чтобы сохранялись несколько записей (причём с удалением это прокатывает). Либо вообще менять сохранение?

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось таки всё массовое сохранение перекидывать в метод CHANGESET_BEGIN и CHANGESET_PROCESS. Хотя массовое удаление отрабатывает через DefferedGroup.